# custom css background image not recognised even after .ms-backgroundImage override

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have a custom html master page, with its own stylesheet, on which the footer has background image set to them. The CSS is  below. But sharepoint 2013 doesnt recognise this background image. I dont think the url is wrong as every other image on the page works. Can someone please help with this ?

```
.spfooter.ms-backgroundImage
{
background-image:url('Images/bottombg.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try marking it as important

```
.spfooter.ms-backgroundImage { background-image:url('Images/bottombg.png') !important; }
```

Comment: Nope, it still does not work.

Comment: .ms-backgroundImage and .spfooter both classes are on same element? Can you please copy paste footer structure over here?

Comment: <td style="height: 200px" class="spfooter" align="center"></td>

Comment: where is this .ms-backgroundImage class?

Comment: isnt the .ms-backgroundImage just to override the default sharepoint OOB ? should I include that on the td class ?

Comment: Yes..otherwise it will never know for which element you want background image.

Comment: so should I change the td to <td style="height: 200px" class="spfooter.ms-backgroundImage" align="center"></td>

Comment: keep it as it is. Just use this CSS .spfooter{ background-image:url('Images/bottombg.png') !important; }

Comment: I tried that and still no luck